# Node fs.unlink does not delete the files immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

I have an issue with node fs.unlink

I have a function that writes files to disk storage extracts data from the these files then deletes the files

```js
const parseShpFile = async ({
    cpgFile,
    dbfFile,
    prjFile,
    qmdFile,
    shpFile,
    shxFile,
}) => {
    // saving binary files to local machine

    const dbfPath = await saveBinaryToLocalMachine(dbfFile);
    const shpPath = await saveBinaryToLocalMachine(shpFile);

    //reading files from local machine using shapefile
    const shpParsedData = await shapefile
        .open(shpPath, dbfPath)
        .then((src) => src.read())
        .then(async (data) => {
            
            await deleteFilesFromLocal([shpPath, dbfPath]);
            return data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log("Error", e);
        });

    return shpParsedData;
};
```

the delete function is

```js
const deleteFilesFromLocal = async (filePaths) => {
    for (const filePath of filePaths) {
        try {
            await fsP.unlink(path.resolve(filePath));

        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error in deleting file", filePath);
        }
    }

    // log after delete finishes
    console.log("DELETE CALLED")
    return;
};
```

the write function is

```js
const saveBinaryToLocalMachine = async (binaryFile) => {
    const name = binaryFile.name.split("/")[2];
    const binary = await binaryFile.async("nodebuffer");
    const writePath = path.resolve(`./db/tmp/${name}`);

    try {
        await fsP.writeFile(writePath, binary);
        // Log after the file is saved
        console.log("file saved");

        return writePath;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

The issue is when I run this code the files are not removed from the desk until the server restarts or shutdowns.

Before server restart or shutdown

[image]

After the server restarted.

[image]

Logs

[image]

Issue when API called for 2nd Time

[image]

Comment: Aside from the fact that's highly discouraged to use synchronous operations (like `unlinkSync` ) in an asynchronous environment (you can use `await unlink(...)` from the `fs/promises` API instead): Are you sure it's not just the file tree not being properly refreshed?

Comment: Or even better: `await Promise.allSettled(filePaths.map(fp => unlink(path.resolve(fp)))`

Comment: The issue is when I try to hit the API for the 2nd time there is an error that says "Cannot open file <file name>" which occurs because of the faulty delete

Comment: I tried await ```fsP.unlink(path.resolve(filePath));``` where fsP  is the  ```fs/promises``` same issue

Comment: Then I ask: Are you sure the `deleteFilesFromLocal` has been called (and ended) before the second call to the API arrives? Assume what happens if for instance `src.read()` throws an error? You will never call `deleteFiles`. My point is: It's quite a bold assumption, that something that is contained in node practically from the very beginning (and effectefly is just a wrapper for a syscall to the underlying OS) suddenly stopped to work ...

Comment: Why is `deleteFilesFromLocal()` an `async` function?

Comment: I changed the unlinkSync to unlink and imported it from fs/promises did the same thing for the write binary to disk. same issue

Comment: Add some breakpoints (or `console.log`s) to the very beginning and very end of your methods to see the execution order. I assume, the second request arrives, before the first one finished ...

Comment: The Node `unlink()` method is basically a direct call-through to the underlying system API to unlink a node from a directory. It is not broken.

Comment: I updated the code to add the saveBinaryToLocalMachine  function and the new delete.
I also added the logs and the code flow seemed to be correct 2 file saves happen then 1 delete is called for both repeated n times. which seems correct

Comment: Yet the issue seems to happen

Comment: Please add the updated code and the output of the logs to your question

Comment: Updated the code and arrachet the logs image also added the 2nd time API error issue

Comment: Well, your log doesn't contain the output `DELETED` even once ... Thus, the delete function did not finish. Probably because something (maybe whatever that `src` in `src.read()` is)  still holds a lock on that file.  If there is a `shapefile.open()` maybe there is a `.close()` too? ...

Comment: The DELETE CALL is deleted sorry did not update logs

Comment: Can you create and post a [mcve]?

Comment: @derpirscher there is no shapefile.close the open handles that stuff 
also the .read is an async function and I am waiting for it by using then

Comment: @derpirscher why would it be highly discouraged to use sync operations in an async context? Don't you think that if it was an issue no code would work at all since most code is synchronous! Typically an assignment is synchronous, the vast majority of class constructs are synchronous, an if is synchronous like is a for loop...

Comment: @EricMORAND  I admit I was a bit sloppy in my words: What I meant was: don't use synchronous **I/O operations** (like file, database or network access) in an asynchronous context. Because JS is single threaded and a synchronous file/network access blocks the one and only execution thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the shapefile lib ***This is not mentioned in the lib docs example***

But there is a function called   `src.cancel` that is called when the stream is destroyed

so the code that worked is

```js
const parseShpFile = async ({
    cpgFile,
    dbfFile,
    prjFile,
    qmdFile,
    shpFile,
    shxFile,
}) => {
    // saving binary files to local machine

    const dbfPath = await saveBinaryToLocalMachine(dbfFile);
    const shpPath = await saveBinaryToLocalMachine(shpFile);

    //reading files from local machine using shapefile
    const src = await shapefile.open(shpPath, dbfPath);
    const shpParsedData = await src.read();
    await src.cancel(); // <=====

    await deleteFilesFromLocal([shpPath, dbfPath]);

    return shpParsedData;
};
```